# PHP string length

Tags: php, string, standards, php-internals

[PHP coding standards](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/CODING_STANDARDS?view=co) say:

> ... PHP holds the length property of each string, and that it
>       shouldn't be calculated with strlen(). Write your functions in a such
>       a way so that they'll take advantage of the length property, both
>       for efficiency and in order for them to be binary-safe. ...

How can I access this length property? Or do I misunderstand it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Ignacio mentioned in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4161983/427992):

> They're talking about the C function, not the PHP function. The C
>   function will stop counting after the first \0, but PHP strings can
>   contain \0 elsewhere other than the end.

That document is most likely about how to extend PHP's engine, rather than programming in PHP itself.

Answer (score 3):

These coding standards are for not intended for web sites developpers using PHP, but for the developpers of the PHP engine itself.

PHP is developped using the C language, and the `strlen` function to avoid is the C one, not the PHP one.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a "property" in the sense that it would be in other languages (like C#).

You cannot do:
    `myString.Length;`

Instead you would need to do:
    `strlen(myString);`